# How populate a MySQL database with random values?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [random data using php & mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676860/random-data-using-php-mysql)

I need to populate my database with random values, like 'lorem ipsum dolor ...' just to make some tests. 
Does anyone know how do that ?
Or a website that could generate this values to my tables ?

I want to fill my fields with random values, like 'lorem ipsum' for example.

Comment: Google for "test data generator" - in the past, I've used DBMonster, which worked pretty well...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+random+test+data plenty of ideas in amongst that lot.

Answer (score 1):

Theres many way to do this. A php script and a loop may help would probably be the quickest and easiest approach. Use a lipsum generator, explode the text on spaces, then use each one in the array for a label.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
http://www.lipsum.com/
```

Comment: No dude, =]
What I mean was fill my field with 'lorem ipsum' values, got it ?